# Blazor: Apply Pagination with Entiy Framework on Datatable.Js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor project that uses Entity Framework and Binds to DataTable.js using JavaScript InterOp.

The project works well but in cases where records loaded from my table are bulky i experience delay and my app crashes at some point.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered"
                   id="example"
                   width="100%"
                   cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-size:14px">
                        <th>FEEDER ID</th>
                        <th>FEEDER NAME</th>
                        <th>FEEDER TYPE</th>
                        <th>DISTRICT ID</th>
                        <th>TCN 132Kv ID</th>
                        <th>INJECTION ID </th>
                        <th>FEEDER NO</th>
                        <th>FEEDER LENGTH </th>
                        <th>STATUS</th>
                        <th>FEEDER CODE</th>
                        <th>DOWNLOAD MAP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var data in feederview)
                    {
                        <tr style="font-size:14px">
                            <td>@data.FeederId</td>
                            <td>@data.FeederName</td>
                            <td>@data.FeederType</td>
                            <td>@data.DistrictId</td>
                            <td>@data.Tcn132kv33kvId</td>
                            <td>@data.InjectionssId</td>
                            <td>@data.FeederNo</td>
                            <td>@data.FeederLength</td>
                            <td>@data.Status</td>
                            <td>@data.FeederCode</td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <button class="btn-info btn-sm" id="btnDelete" value="delete"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x " aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is my HTML Code definition with bindings

**C# Blazor Server side code using Entity Framework**

```
     feederview = context.FeederView.Select(c => new FeederView()
            {
                FeederId = c.FeederId,
                FeederName = c.FeederName,
                FeederType = c.FeederType,
                DistrictId = c.DistrictId,
                Tcn132kv33kvId = c.Tcn132kv33kvId,
                Tcn132kv33kvTransformerId = c.Tcn132kv33kvTransformerId,
                InjectionssId = c.InjectionssId,
                InjectionssTransformerId = c.InjectionssTransformerId,
                FeederNo = c.FeederNo,
                FeederLength = c.FeederLength,
                Status = c.Status,
                FeederCode = c.FeederCode,

            }).ToList();
```

The list returns up to 2000 records which makes my app slow and crashes.

[image]

**Above is the sample records shown ( for this i just loaded small records)**

How can i add pagination to Datatable.js to allow me retrieve a particular amount of records on load and the remaining loads later?

Comment: You can refer to this step https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-pagination/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to look at server-side processing https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Otherwise, perhaps there is a way of utilising the new virtualization feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0